# AppService in Azure and DNSs managed by GoDaddy: SSL issue when Azure's IP changes

Tags: azure, ssl, cloud-hosting

I have an AppService hosted in Azure and DNSs managed by GoDaddy. When the IP address of the AppService changes, the SSL certificate is no longer valid (you browse the site and you get a privacy error because the certificate is not in the correct domain). In order to fix this issue, I need to go to GoDaddy and change the IP address.

**My configuration in GoDaddy:**

- **A record** referring to the AppService IP address
- **CNAME www record** referring to the app service URL xxx.azurewebsites.net

**SSL certificate in Azure:**

- www.domainname.com: SNI based
- domainname.com: IP SSL based

Note about IP SSL based certificate: changing both to SNI based did not fix the issue.

**Any ideas to avoid having to update the IP address in GoDaddy every time Azure changes the ip of the AppService?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try pointing your GoDaddy CName www record to sni.[website].azurewebsites.net.  A detailed write-up can be found here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/08/11/azure-app-service-ip-based-ssl-and-sni-based-ssl-configuration/